# How to reduce a Jacobian to a diagonal matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning, machine-learning, jacobian

I am reading this paper and I came across [this](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/index.html#sec4.2). From the 4th paragraph:

> We know that element-wise operations imply that $f_{i}$ is purely a function of $w_i$ and $g_i$ is purely a function of $x_i$.

I tried a lot to understand this but I'm unable to understand that. How can we conclude this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The author is talking about the case where the functions $f_{i}, g_{i}$ are functions only of $w_{i}$, respectively $x_{i}$

Comment: You're saying that he refers to only those cases where $f_i$ and $g_i$ are functions of only $w_i$ and $x_i$ respectively, and only in such cases the diagonal element-wise condition holds true?